# AcivityTracing disabled but tracing is still active - Entlib 6

Tags: logging, enterprise-library

When I disable Activity Tracing it nevertheless logs all log statements below??
The severity level of my logging category is set to All.
I would assume by disabling it, that it will not log the last 5 log statements, as these are activity tracing events,
but it still does trace.

For example, if I turn disable logging through a global logging filter it will won't log anything.

The only way to make this work is querying the `IsTracingEnabled()` method manually.

```
Loggers.Instance.Write("Verbose", LogCategory.Database.ToString(), 1, 1, TraceEventType.Verbose);         //  1
Loggers.Instance.Write("Information", LogCategory.Database.ToString(), 1, 1, TraceEventType.Information); //  2
Loggers.Instance.Write("Warning", LogCategory.Database.ToString(), 1, 1, TraceEventType.Warning);         //  3
Loggers.Instance.Write("Error", LogCategory.Database.ToString(), 1, 1, TraceEventType.Error);             //  4
Loggers.Instance.Write("Critical", LogCategory.Database.ToString(), 1, 1, TraceEventType.Critical);       //  5
Loggers.Instance.Write("Resume", LogCategory.Database.ToString(), 1, 1, TraceEventType.Resume);           //  6
Loggers.Instance.Write("Start", LogCategory.Database.ToString(), 1, 1, TraceEventType.Start);             //  7
Loggers.Instance.Write("Stop", LogCategory.Database.ToString(), 1, 1, TraceEventType.Stop);               //  8
Loggers.Instance.Write("Suspend", LogCategory.Database.ToString(), 1, 1, TraceEventType.Suspend);         //  9
Loggers.Instance.Write("Transfer", LogCategory.Database.ToString(), 1, 1, TraceEventType.Transfer);       // 10
```

Here I disable tracing:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you disable ActivityTracing then it will disable all traces when using the TraceManager class!

```
using (TraceMgr.StartTrace("UI Events")) // this will not trace anything
{

}
```